# Add a class to the first child in a loop using Middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman, static-site

I am creating a slider for my blog and I want to add a collection of featured items to it, The slider requires that the first child load with the class `selected`.

How can I do something like `if first child do this` `else do that`

Here is what I have so far:

```
<ul class="cd-hero-slider">
    <% blog.articles.select {|a| a.data[:featured] }.each do |article| %>
      <li class="selected" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447014421976-7fec21d26d86?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=c82e04e1201234889daab5427f481731')">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <h2><%= link_to article.title, article %></h2>
          <p><%= article.summary(250) %></p>
          <%= link_to 'Read More', article, :class => 'cd-btn' %>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use each_with_index instead of each - this will give you the object but also the position into the array, first being 0:

```
<% blog.articles.select {|a| a.data[:featured] }.each_with_index do |article, index| %>
  <% if index == 0 %>
    <li>I'm the first!</li>
  <% else %>
    <li>Not the first</li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```